# How can one add a ">" symbol while producing survival curves in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to add the greater than symbol ">" in ggsurvplot? in the figure legend?

Here is my sample dataset and code for this problem:

```
structure(list(X = 1:26, OS = c(59, 115, 156, 421, 431, 448,  464,
475, 477, 563, 638, 744, 769, 770, 803, 855, 1040, 1106,  1129, 1206,
1227, 268, 329, 353, 365, 377), OS_event = c(1, 1,  1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,  1, 1, 0), age = c("> 50
years", "> 50 years", "> 50 years", "> 50 years",  "> 50 years", "> 50
years", "> 50 years", "> 50 years", "> 50 years",  "> 50 years", "> 50
years", "> 50 years", "> 50 years", "< 50 years",  "< 50 years", "< 50
years", "< 50 years", "< 50 years", "< 50 years",  "< 50 years", "< 50
years", "< 50 years", "< 50 years", "< 50 years",  "< 50 years", "< 50
years"), resid.ds = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,  2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), rx = c(1L,
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,  2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  2L), ecog.ps = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-26L), class = "data.frame")
Load data and packages
pacman::p_load(pacman, party, rio, tidyverse) 
library(survival) 
library(survminer) 
library(ggtext)

ovarian <- read.csv("~/Desktop/ovarian.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 

ovarian$OS = as.numeric(ovarian$OS) ovarian$OS_event =
as.numeric(ovarian$OS_event)

# Run KM plot: 
ggsurvplot(survfit(Surv(OS, OS_event) ~ ovarian$age,
                    data = ovarian), 
            risk.table = TRUE,
            pval = TRUE,
            pval.coord = c(72,0.8),
            legend.labs = c("< 55 years", "> 55 years"), 
            title = "                              OS by binarised median age",
            legend = "right",
            legend.title = "Binarised median age", 
            break.x.by=24,
            palette = c("red", "blue"), 
            xlab="Time (Months)",
            xlim=c(0,96))
```

However, this generates the following error:

> Error: gridtext has encountered a tag that isn't supported yet:
>
> Only a very limited number of tags are currently
> supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth reviewing what's actually happening. The `ggtext` function attempts to parse the labels using tags and the blockquote tag (`>`) is [not supported](https://github.com/wilkelab/gridtext/blob/master/R/process-tags.R#L143-L166). So we need some way to escape the tag. I couldn't find a documented way.

It's a bit of a hack, but I've added a zero width space unicode character (`\u200B`) before the `>` to break the tag:

```
ggsurvplot(survfit(Surv(OS, OS_event) ~ ovarian$age,
                    data = ovarian), 
            risk.table = TRUE,
            pval = TRUE,
            pval.coord = c(72,0.8),
            legend.labs = c("< 55 years", "\u200B> 55 years"), 
            title = "                              OS by binarised median age",
            legend = "right",
            legend.title = "Binarised median age", 
            break.x.by=24,
            palette = c("red", "blue"), 
            xlab="Time (Months)",
            xlim=c(0,96))
```

[image]

As an aside, you don't have to manually center the title. You can add the following argument to `ggsurvplot`:

```
ggtheme = theme_survminer() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Thanks! On a side-note, is there a way to adjust the height of the plot title? For instance, can one increase the gap between the main plot title and the underlying plot?

Comment: Perfect - thank you! There is one more subject where I wanted to get your advice; is there a way to assign superscript numbers to categories mentioned in survival plot? For instance using the example of your plot above, would it be possible to mark the "years" in the risk table and the legend as a superscript character? I have  tried using the "^" symbol in the legend.labs part of the code but it only implements the change in the risk table, not the legend. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: If you can, I can't figure it out. I would suggest posting a new question.